# Migrate Firebase Realtime Database to Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for the best way to migrate my apps database which is using firebase realtime database to the new Cloud Firestore database. I am confident for the project I am working on I don't need to make any data schema changes, so I am pretty much just trying to 1-1 map it. Firebase has suggested on their site to just write a script to do this, but I am not sure of the best way to go about that. Has anyone already made a script that accomplishes this?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/firestore-for-rtdb

Comment: yep, aware of that link, but they basically just suggest write a script, but that is not what this question is asking.

Comment: Unlikely anyone will have a generic script yet for this since it will likely be custom to each person's particular use case and requirements.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Can you link to where they are mentioning that you can write a script to do it?

Comment: I think the removed the migration part

Comment: @DanMcGrath well maybe at least a template script could prove helpful that say moves one table from the realtime database to the firestore database

Comment: What kind of data volumes have you tested your scripts on? I tried my own (from JSON) but found that my dataset was too big for Firestore.

Comment: @Netg, yeah my below script does not work for a big volume.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote up a little node script that migrated things in a quick and dirty way and it worked quite nicely.

It is below if anyone else is interested.

**Note: This should only be used if your data model in the realtime database was completely flat and did not have much nested data, and you intend on keeping your data flat as well in Firestore**

To run this script just create a node file called index.js and throw it in a directory along with your service account file and raw json file from the realtime database export and run the following from command line.

```
$ node index.js
```

Script implementation below.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./config.json");
var database = require("./database.json");
var async = require ('async');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var db = admin.firestore();

var allEntityNames = Object.keys(database);

var asyncTasks = [];

for (var i in allEntityNames) {
  var entityName = allEntityNames[i];
  var entity = database[entityName];
  var entityKeys = Object.keys(entity);

  console.log("began migrating "+ entityName);
  for (var j in entityKeys) {
    var entityKey = entityKeys[j];
    var dict = entity[entityKey];
    asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
      db.collection(entityName).doc(entityKey).set(dict)
        .then(function() {
          callback();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          callback();
        });
    });
  }
  async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
    console.log("Finished migrating "+ entityName);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I wrote a script in `Node-Js` that use batch in writing to Firestore (batch is super fast and suitable for write may items)
here is my code, just change files name to your's name and run `node YOUR_FILE_NAME.js`

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./firestore-config.json');
var database = require('./database.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'YOUR_FILE_STORE_DB_URL',
});

var db = admin.firestore();
var allEntityNames = Object.keys(database);
var counter = 0;
var commitCounter = 0;
var batches = [];
batches[commitCounter] = db.batch();
var ref = db.collection('users');
allEntityNames.forEach(function(k, i) {
  if (counter <= 498) {
    var thisRef = ref.doc(k);
    batches[commitCounter].set(thisRef, database[k]);
    counter = counter + 1;
  } else {
    counter = 0;
    commitCounter = commitCounter + 1;
    batches[commitCounter] = db.batch();
  }
});
for (var i = 0; i < batches.length; i++) {
  batches[i].commit().then(function() {
    console.count('wrote batch');
  });
}
```

1. if you don't have `Node-Js` on your machine, google to install it. it is not so hard.
2. you can download `firestore-config.json` from your firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with a very basic node script and I hope it will serve as an example to the next one having this issue:

```
require('firebase/firestore')
const fs = require('fs')
const { initializeApp, firestore } = require('firebase/app')

const UID = 'asdfasdf' // UID of the user you are migrating

initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID
})

// db.json is the downloaded copy from my firebasedatabase
fs.readFile('db.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    const json = JSON.parse(data)
    const readings = json.readings[UID]
    const result = Object.values(readings)
    result.forEach(({ book, chapter, date }) =>
        // In my case the migration was easy, I just wanted to move user's readings to their own collection
        firestore().collection(`users/${UID}/readings`)
            .add({ date: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(date)), chapter, book })
            .catch(console.error)
    )
    console.log('SUCCESS!')
})
```

Of course you can also iterate twice to do it for every user but in my case it was not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent 3rd party npm package to help with importing, it boils down to basically one line:

```
await firestoreService.restore({ "my-table": myTable });
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import

Answer (score 0):

@Luke solution is great but nowadays it didn't work for the entire collection, it saves only the first document, so I modified it for using Promise.all

```html
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

var db = admin.firestore();
var allEntityNames = Object.keys(database);


(async function () {
  for (var i in allEntityNames) {
    var entityName = allEntityNames[i];
    var entity = database[entityName];
    var entityKeys = Object.keys(entity);

    const promises = entityKeys.map(async (entityKey) => {
      var dict = entity[entityKey];
      return await db
        .collection(entityName)
        .doc(entityKey)
        .set(dict)
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("error=>", error);
        });
    });

    console.log("promises.length", promises.length);
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('Migration done!')
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi i have created a script for the same

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore'; 
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore, private angularfire: AngularFireDatabase ) {}
convert() { 
this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('requests');//ref() 
this.angularfire.list('/requests/').auditTrail().subscribe((data: any) => { 
_.each(data, element =>{
this.itemsCollection.doc(element.key).set(element.payload.val()) .then((result) => { }); }); });}
```

Comment: can you add steps to run this?

Comment: yes
1) configure your firebase project and then  
2) Add in TS file
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore'; 
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore, private angularfire: AngularFireDatabase ) {}
convert() { 
this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('requests');//ref() 
this.angularfire.list('/requests/').auditTrail().subscribe((data: any) => { 
_.each(data, element =>{
this.itemsCollection.doc(element.key).set(element.payload.val()) .then((result) => { }); }); });}